# How to detect Applet is loaded so its triggered only once

Tags: java, applet, load

This is `myApp.html` to load an applet:

```
<applet
archive="xxx.jar,xxx2.jar"
name = "XXX"
code= "XXX.class"
width=1280 height=800>
<PARAM name="java_version" value="1.6.0_27">
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx512m">
</applet>
```

So everytime I open `myApp.html` in a browser, an applet is loaded. But everytime I open `myApp.html` in a new browser's tab or reload the previous tab, a new applet instance is loaded.

How to avoid the same applet is loaded if there is instance already initialized?

Comment: So far you've asked 17 questions and only accepted a single answer.  Please revisit [you earlier questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1205972/baizen?tab=questions) & correct that, as it seems you are abusing the free help being offered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent (fortunately for the empowered end user) a second page opening.

If you can handle the applet being shown as a free floating element (*not* embedded in a web page), the solution would (OK.. *might*<sup>1</sup>) be to launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & use the `SingleInstanceService` of the JNLP API to ensure only one instance.  Here is a [demo. of the service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis).

1. The `SingleInstanceService` works well with desktop applications based on `JFrame`, but I've never tried using it with an applet.